# filter object in javacscript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object

I have object which contains child object as well. I want to filter them. I have written a filter code but stuck between to how to create a new object with same relation. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wtm6c4m4/)

```
var x = 0
var newobj;

function loop(obj, type1, type2) {
    for (i in obj) {
        if (obj[i].shape == type1 && obj[i].health == type2) {
            $('div').append(obj[i].shape + '-' + obj[i].health + '<br>')
            if (!x) {
                newobj = obj[i];
            } else {
                newobj.children = obj[i]
            }
            x++
        }
        loop(obj[i].children, type1, type2)
    }
}

function filter() {
    loop(obj, 'circle', 'red')
}

filter()

console.log(newobj)
```

**EDIT**

Edited [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wtm6c4m4/1/) with small and clear data and expected result is given below

```
{
    "shape": "circle",
    "health": "red",
    "children": [
        {
            "shape": "circle",
            "health": "red"
        },
        {
            "shape": "circle",
            "health": "red"
        },
        {
            "shape": "circle",
            "health": "red",
            "children": [
                {
                    "shape": "circle",
                    "health": "red"
                },
                {
                    "shape": "circle",
                    "health": "red"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Old picture -

[image]

expected result-

[image]

Comment: You will get more responses when you make your question clear with some sample inputs, expected output and the actual problem you are facing.

Comment: I would have a look at binary search tree removal which is a very similar concept: http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Binary_search_tree/Removal

Comment: I would also recommend looking at a way to remove elements from the tree rather than building a new tree entirely

Answer (score 1):

That's challenging! There is a way in removing nodes that doesn't pass the filter. If you don't want to, just clone the tree structure.

First, let's create a root element so the tree don't split if the first element doesn't match the filter condition:

```
var tree = {"shape":"root","health":"ultraviolet","children":obj};
// obj is your structure in your question
```

Now the removeNode function would be

```
function removeNode(victim,parent) {
  // remove the victim from parent's children
  var target = parent.children.indexOf(victim);
  if(target>-1) parent.children.splice(target,1);
  // add victim's children to parent's children
  if(victim.children) parent.children = parent.children.concat(victim.children);
  // don't do this if you need a clone
  delete(victim);
}
```

And the filter function would be

```
function filter(root,shape,health) {
  if(root.children) root.children.forEach(function(o) {
    filter(o,shape,health);
    if(!(o.shape==shape && o.health==health) && o.shape!="root") {
      removeNode(o,root);
      // possible optimization: you could skip nodes which passed already
      filter(root,shape,health);
    }
  });
}
```

So you can do

```
filter(tree,"circle","red");
```

To get your desired result.

Comment: Thanks jan for your answer, I have been waiting for answer from long time, I will check the answer in evening and get back to you